# Dropdownlist viewdata?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a collection named as product which have two fields Id and Name.

For creating dropdown list I am using

```
ViewData["Geography"] = new SelectList( parent,"Id","Id");
```

I want to display Id + Name in the dropdown list.

I tried following things which didnot work

```
ViewData["Geography"] = new SelectList( parentCollection,"Id","Id Name");

ViewData["Geography"] = new SelectList( parentCollection,"Id","Id" + "Name");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query from `parentCollection` and create a new property with `select new`

```
ViewData["Geography"] = 
    new SelectList((from s in parentCollection select new { 
        ID = s.Id,
        IdAndName = s.Id + " " + s.Name}), 
       "ID", 
       "IdAndName", 
        null);
```